# Showing All the Posts in the Loop

Tags: jquery

this code here

```
<div class="col">
        <?php gab_dynamic_sidebar('Subnews1');?>

        <?php
        $postnr = of_get_option('of_wn_nr8') + of_get_option('of_wn_nr8a');
        if (intval($postnr) > 0 ) { ?>
            <span class="catname"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8'));?>"><?php echo get_cat_name(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8')); ?></a></span>
            <?php
            $count = 1;
            $args = array(
             'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate,
              'posts_per_page' => $postnr,
              'cat' => of_get_option('of_wn_cat8', 1)
            );
            $gab_query = new WP_Query();$gab_query->query($args); 
            while ($gab_query->have_posts()) : $gab_query->the_post(); if (of_get_option('of_dnd') == 1) { $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; }
            ?>
            <div class="featuredpost<?php if($count == of_get_option('of_wn_nr8') or $count == $postnr) { echo ' lastpost'; } ?>">


                <?php if ($count <= of_get_option('of_wn_nr8')) { ?>

                    <h2 class="posttitle">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpnewspaper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>                       
                    <div class="opinion_wrapper">
                    <?php
                        gab_media(array(   'imgtag' => 1,   'link' => 1,
                            'name' => 'wn-subnews',
                            'enable_video' => 0,
                            'catch_image' => of_get_option('of_catch_img', 0),
                            'enable_thumb' => 1,
                            'resize_type' => 'c',
                            'media_width' => 120, 
                            'media_height' => 103, 
                            'thumb_align' => 'alignleft',
                            'enable_default' => 0
                        ));
                    ?>  
                    <div class="opinion_marker"><!-- opinion marker --></div>                   
                    </div>
                    <p><?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),27); ?>&hellip;</p>

                    <?php gab_postmeta(); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>

                    <a class="listtitle" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpnewspaper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                <?php } ?>

            </div><!-- .featuredpost -->
            <?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- .col -->
```

, is this, shown in this image here http://d.pr/i/7efk ,

on this site http://dev.dmichel.net/adv/ .

what i need to happen is to show all 4 posts, rather than just 1.

What I tried to do to show all 4 posts is this

```
<?php
            $count = 1;
            $args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 4,
              'cat' => of_get_option('of_wn_cat8', 1)
            );
            $gab_query = new WP_Query();$gab_query->query($args); 
            while ($gab_query->have_posts()) : $gab_query->the_post(); }
            ?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I'd like help showing all 4 posts above the titles

Comment: Hi Danny. Are you asking for help with jQuery?

Comment: the weird thing is that its equally as much jquery as it is wordpress, but i have the jquery part down http://jsfiddle.net/AsScy/

Comment: So you don't need help making the toggle effect? Im confused. Please, can you re-edit your question to specify the exact problem you are facing? It will be easier for people to help.

Comment: I have the toggle effect down http://jsfiddle.net/AsScy/ i just need to figure out ho wto display all 4 articles

Comment: All 4 articles at once? Or ... you have 4 articles that you want to appear once you toggle them?

Comment: Yes, I tried <span class="catname"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8'));?>"><?php echo get_cat_name(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8')); ?></a></span>
    <?php
    $count = 1;
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'cat' => of_get_option('of_wn_cat8', 1)
    );
    $gab_query = new WP_Query();$gab_query->query($args); 
    while ($gab_query->have_posts()) : $gab_query->the_post();
    ?>

Comment: 4 articles that i want to appear when i toggle them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7583/discussion-between-aliyah-and-danny-michel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fiddle for anyone that is interested [HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/AU7Tm/)

Here is the javascript I used also to give the smooth scroll for an article container.

```
// clicking the links in the article link container
$('#article-links a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);    // save this instance of the click for access inside the loop

    // loop through all the article links and store the numeric value
    $('#article-links a').each(function(al) {
        // if the link being looked at currently matches the html/text of the link that was selected then
        if ($(this).html() == $this.html()) {
            // set the scroll position by multiplying the article previews height by the ordered number link
            // that was selected (i.e 500*1 will scroll the preview div up/down to scrollTop: 500)
            var articlePos = parseInt($('#article-preview').height())*al;

            // animate the scroll for a smooth scroll               
            $('#article-preview').animate({ scrollTop: articlePos });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you steven. You can bet I'll be using this in my theme.